# Non canonical singularities of moduli spaces of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, coarse-moduli-spaces

Is it true that for any $g\geq 1$ and $n$ such that $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ has dimension at least two the locus in $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ parametrizing reducible curves which are union of an elliptic tails with $6$ automorphisms and a curve of genus $g-1$ is a locus of non canonical singularities? Could it happen that for small values of $g$ these singularities are canonical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We denote by $\Delta_{1}$ the image in $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ of $\overline{M}_{1,1}\times \overline{M}_{g-1,n+1}$, the divisor parametrizing curves with elliptic tails.

Let $Z_6$ the image of $[E_6]\times \overline{M}_{g-1,n+1}\subset \Delta_{1}$, the codimension two loci where the elliptic tail has six automorphisms.

For any $g\geq 1$ the sub-variety $Z_6$ is a locus of codimension three non-canonical singularities. Indeed it is a locus of $\frac{1}{3}(1,1)$ transversal singularities.